# Azure Sign-in error code 500119 when using Get-AzureADWHfBKeys - Redirect URIs with urn: schemes are prohibited

Tags: azure, powershell, windows-hello

I am trying to use "Get-AzureADWHfBKeys" in PowerShell but i am getting the below error

Install-Module -Name WHfBTools -Force
Import-Module -Name WHfBTools
Install-Module -Name MSAL.PS -RequiredVersion 4.5.1.1 -force
Import-Module MSAL.PS
Get-AzureADWHfBKeys -Tenant "example" -UserPrincipalName "example

Get-AzureADWHfBKeys info:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/using-whfbtools-powershell-module-for-cleaning-up-orphaned-windows-hello-for-business-keys-779d1f3f-bb2d-c495-0f6b-9aeb940eeafb

Error:
Failure reason
Redirect URIs with urn: schemes are prohibited. Use a different scheme, or https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

Application
Azure Active Directory PowerShell
Application ID
1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894
Resource
Windows Azure Active Directory
Resource ID
00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Failure reason
> Redirect URIs with urn: schemes are prohibited. Use a different scheme, or https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient: -

According to the above error, it means that you need to use a different redirect URL. To do that, Go to `Azure AD >> App registrations` and then find the application with the error message ID (1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894) or the application used for the PowerShell script.

Reconfigure the application to use this `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient` as the Redirect URI.

*Using above mentioned way, I tried to retrieve the keys as you did follow by installing the required modules and was able to get the outcome as expected.*

```
 Install-Module -Name WHfBTools -Scope CurrentUser
 Import-Module -Name WHfBTools
 Install-Module -Name MSAL.PS -RequiredVersion 4.5.1.1 -Scope CurrentUser
 Import-Module MSAL.PS
```

```
Get-AzureADWHfBKeys -Tenant "<TENANT_ID>" -UserPrincipalName xxxxx
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot find this application ID in App Registration or Enterprise applications. in the blog post  the AppId “1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894“ is reported as Azure Active Directory PowerShell”.  https://m365security.net/2021/04/05/detect-when-compromised-end-user-connects-to-azure-ad-for-reconnaissance/

Comment: according to this post , it is hidden .  For those curious, yes you do need an Azure Application for oauth as specified here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow
However, PowerShell is already a registered application in Azure (although hidden). AppID 1b730954-1685-4b74-9bfd-dac224a7b894       https://x.com/Haus3c/status/1473846735558651908?s=20

Comment: You can find APP ID by going to `Azure AD >> App registrations` as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/V0yCt7d.png). @EddardStark